# DropDown list on a WebService in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a series of questions which are on a webservice.

I know how to retrieve my recordings (my questions) via a for loop.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="listing" *ngFor="let item of questions" >
    <li>- {{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

**TS**

```
    questions;
    selectedQuestion;
    
    this.api.getUserStatus(this.user)
    .subscribe((response) => {
                
        console.log("HELLO : " + JSON.stringify(response));

        if (response['PAGEACCEUIL'].ISFIRST == "TRUE") {
                    
            this.goToFase(3);
        } else {
                    
            this.goToFase(2);
        }
        
        this.questions = response['PAGEACCEUIL'].TEXTE.QUESTION
        this.selectedQuestion = response['PAGEACCEUIL'].TEXTE.QUESTION

        console.log("My Questions  (Display): " + JSON.stringify(this.questions));
        console.log("My Questions (DROPDOWN) : " + JSON.stringify(this.selectedQuestion));              
});
```

I get my recordings

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyhKl.png)

Now, I would like to use a dropdown list except that, I don't understand the syntax...

My dropdown list is empty ... I retrieve 11 times `item` but not my recordings.

```
<select>
       <option *ngFor="let item of selectedQuestion"> {{item}</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Could it be because you have a missing closing bracket when you try to render your item as an option? I can see there is `{{item}` and it should be `{{item}}`. Maybe that's why you see `{{item}` 11 times.

Comment: @Octavian Mărculescu: Yeesss !! Sorry, I did not pay attention